# Jquery Validation - Rules not having an affect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Help!

Trying to setup Jquery validation on a form, and well, its ignoring any rule I try and add.

Only the inline rules are working such as type="email" required e.t.c.

I've tried to add the validation in several ways:

```
function onloadCallback() {
    console.log("test");
    $("#hiddenRecaptcha").rules("add", {
        required: function() {
            console.log("grecaptcha.getResponce()");
            if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Nothing gets logged to the console, it doesn't appear the 'onloadCallback' function is ever called.

I've also got:

```
var validate2 = $("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            email: true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 20
        },
        hiddenRecaptcha: {
            required: function() {
                console.log("grecaptcha.getResponce()");
                if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // fix-up placement of error label after first existing label
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log('I tried to validate');
        console.log(grecaptcha.getResponse());
        if (element.context.type == 'checkbox') {
            error.insertAfter(element.next('label'));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Now, I know this bit is working because the error-placement correctly puts in the log 'I tried to validate', however, none of the rules function.

No errors of any sort appearing in the console, it just seems to completely skip all of the rules setup. I can't see any reason why it would do this in the code, since the know the .validate function is running correctly.

Even checking the simple rule, it is quite happy to accept any length E-mail even after I put min-length 20 on there as a test.

There is nothing set to be ignored in the code.

```
<div class="w-100">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Contact Form"  format="%D, %F %d, %Y - %g:%i:%s" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();" style="display: none;">
<!-- Form fields -->
<!-- Name input -->
 <div class="field">
                            <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" type="text" id="name" value="{name}"  required/>
                            <span class="entypo-user icon"></span>
                            <span class="slick-tip left">Enter your name</span>
                        </div>
                            <!-- Email input -->
                        <div class="field">
                            <input name="emailaddy" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" type="email" id="emailaddy" value="{emailaddy}"  required/>
                            <span class="entypo-mail icon"></span>
                            <span class="slick-tip left">Enter a valid email address</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Phone input -->
                        <div class="field">
                            <input name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" type="tel" id="phone" value="{phone}"  required/>
                            <span class="entypo-mobile icon"></span>
                            <span class="slick-tip left">Add your phone number here</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Subject input -->

                        <!-- Message input -->
                        <div class="field">
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" class="message" value="{message}" required></textarea>
                            <span class="entypo-comment icon"></span>
                            <span class="slick-tip left">Add your message here</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LegSgwTAAAAAEfyri8RGqxaqrP1G1IrBeBZ1JuC"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Send button -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="send" form="contact-form" name="send" />
```

Form tags excluded as they are generated by the framework.

I've made a simplier version with no captcha, same code - the recaptch divs.

```
    var validateContact = $("#contact-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    emailaddy: {
                        email: true,
                        minimumlength: 20,
                    },
                },
                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                ignore: "",
                // use debug if you don't want the form to be submitted
                // debug: true,
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
                }
        });
```

Still, there is no minimum length set on email_address, it happily accepts any valid email even test@test.com.

Comment: i am not sure if you can assign a function to a rule. You should use `addMethod` for that and mention in the rules.

Comment: **Show us the relevant HTML markup**.  There are a few mistakes you could have made here.

Comment: Have updated the question with HTML + Updated to avoid confusion with the function. That wasn't the issue, the function seems like it should work and other people are saying it works.

Comment: I don't see any other people here saying your broken code is working.   Your first version tries to validate a hidden field without setting the ignore option. Yes, that would be an issue.  Your second version spelled the `minlength` rule as `minimumlength`... another major problem.  Then your posted answer solves something that's not even contained in your question... a dash within the `name`.  You should have posted the question correctly in the first place.

Comment: How am I meant to post the question differently when I didn't know about any of the other problems? One error would have produced JS errors, the other wouldn't have affected the other rules so couldn't be the cause of the actual question I asked.

Even if I had posted the original HTML and code straight off it wouldn't have helped as it was an issue with the framework renaming the field, so you would have seen the source code and the JS having the correct names. It was only comparing the source and the outputted code that the problem became apparent.

Comment: Conversely, how can anyone possibly answer the question when the actual problem is not part of the OP?  Posting the ***rendered*** HTML and JavaScript would have solved that.  Please review the ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["Create a Minimal Compilable Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pages.

Comment: I realise that, but if I had realised the source code was been processed and changed via the framework at the time, I would have checked that in the first place and there wouldn't have been a problem to post.

Answer (score -1):

Doh, turned out to be an issue with the frame-work renaming the E-mail address field for me. Changing the name, id e.t.c. to emailaddy sorted the issue, so getting rid of the - and _ characters.

Comment: You did not even have `-` characters in the email field name anyplace in your question. **The code as you posted it was working.**  However, the solution to a dash in a `name` would simply be to surround the name in quotes.  Underscores are not an issue.  See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)

Comment: It was an issue with the framework, not with Jquery validation.

Comment: Yes, the code would work, because it wasn't been changed by the framework. 

That was the issue, the framework was changing the id tags on the inputs before they were been output to the page, so they didn't match in the JS and HTML anymore.

The inline ones still ofc worked as they don't care about that.